# Unable to calculate difference between CTE subquery outputs for use in larger PostgreSQL query output column

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression, window-functions

Using PostgreSQL v9.4.5 from Shell I created a database called moments in `psql` by running `create database moments`. I then created a moments table:

```
CREATE TABLE moments
(
  id SERIAL4 PRIMARY KEY,
  moment_type BIGINT NOT NULL,
  flag BIGINT NOT NULL,
  time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE(moment_type, time)
);
INSERT INTO moments (moment_type, flag, time) VALUES (1, 7, '2016-10-29 12:00:00');
INSERT INTO moments (moment_type, flag, time) VALUES (1, -30, '2016-10-29 13:00:00');
INSERT INTO moments (moment_type, flag, time) VALUES (3, 5, '2016-10-29 14:00:00');
INSERT INTO moments (moment_type, flag, time) VALUES (2, 9, '2016-10-29 18:00:00');
INSERT INTO moments (moment_type, flag, time) VALUES (2, -20, '2016-10-29 17:00:00');
INSERT INTO moments (moment_type, flag, time) VALUES (3, 10, '2016-10-29 16:00:00');
```

I run `select * from moments` to view the table:

**Moments Table**

```
 id | moment_type | flag |        time         
----+-------------+------+---------------------
  1 |           1 |    7 | 2016-10-29 12:00:00
  2 |           1 |  -30 | 2016-10-29 13:00:00
  3 |           3 |    5 | 2016-10-29 14:00:00
  4 |           2 |    9 | 2016-10-29 18:00:00
  5 |           2 |  -20 | 2016-10-29 17:00:00
  6 |           3 |   10 | 2016-10-29 16:00:00
```

I then try to write an SQL query that produces the following output, whereby for each pair of duplicate moment_type values it returns the difference between the flag value of the moment_type having the most recent timestamp value, and the flag value of the second most recent timestamp value, and lists the results in ascending order by moment_type.

**Expected SQL Query Output**

```
moment_type | flag | 
------------+------+
          1 |  -37 |  (i.e. -30 - 7)
          2 |   29 |  (i.e.   9 - -20)
          3 |   5  |  (i.e.  10 - 5)
```

The SQL query that I came up with is as follows, which uses the WITH query to write multiple [Common Table Expressions (CET)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/queries-with.html) subqueries for use as temporary tables in the larger SELECT query at the end. I also use an [SQL function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/xfunc-sql.html) to calculate the difference between two of the subquery outputs (alternatively I think I could have just used [DIFFERENCE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188753.aspx) `DIFFERENCE(most_recent_flag, second_most_recent_flag) AS flag` instead of the function):

```
CREATE FUNCTION difference(most_recent_flag, second_most_recent_flag) RETURNS numeric AS $$
  SELECT $1 - $2;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;

-- get two flags that have the most recent timestamps
WITH two_most_recent_flags AS (
SELECT moments.flag
FROM moments
ORDER BY moments.time DESC
LIMIT 2
),
-- get one flag that has the most recent timestamp
most_recent_flag AS (
SELECT *
FROM two_most_recent_flags 
ORDER BY flag DESC
LIMIT 1
), 
-- get one flag that has the second most recent timestamp
second_most_recent_flag AS (
SELECT *
FROM two_most_recent_flags 
ORDER BY flag ASC
LIMIT 1
)
SELECT DISTINCT ON (moments.moment_type)
moments.moment_type,
difference(most_recent_flag, second_most_recent_flag) AS flag
FROM moments
ORDER BY moment_type ASC
LIMIT 2;
```

But when I run the above SQL query in PostgreSQL, it returns the following error:

```
ERROR:  column "most_recent_flag" does not exist
LINE 21: difference(most_recent_flag, second_most_recent_flag) AS fla...
```

**Question**

What techniques can I use and how may I apply them to overcome this error, and calculate and display the differences in the `flag` column to achieve the **Expected SQL Query Output**?

Note: Perhaps the [Window Function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html) may be used somehow as it performs calculations across table rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `lag()` window function:

```
select moment_type, difference
from (
    select *, flag- lag(flag) over w difference
    from moments
    window w as (partition by moment_type order by time)
    ) s
where difference is not null
order by moment_type

 moment_type | difference 
-------------+------------
           1 |        -37
           2 |         29
           3 |          5
(3 rows)
```

Answer (score 1):

One method is to use conditional aggregation.  The window function `row_number()` can be used to identify the first and last time values:

```
select m.moment_type,
       (max(case when seqnum_desc = 1 then flag end) -
        min(case when seqnum_asc = 1 then flag end)
       )
from (select m.*,
             row_number() over (partition by m.moment_type order by m.time) as seqnum_asc,
             row_number() over (partition by m.moment_type order by m.time desc) as seqnum_desc
      from moments m
     ) m
group by m.moment_type;
```